# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'required' - Rest framework model serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is my code

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.Field(source="username", required = False)   
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username')
```

It seems so straight forward. What is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to `CharField`.

```
username = serializers.CharField(source="username", required = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `CharField` and add `allow_blank=True`

```
username = serializers.CharField(source="username", 
                                 required = False,
                                 allow_blank=True)
```